# MySQL query produces correct results, but using PDO produces no results - why?

Tags: php, pdo

**EDIT:** I have changed the title of this question, as I am really getting no results, rather than a NULL result.

I am currently working with PDO on a project of mine, and am having a problem I can't seem to get past. A standard MySQL query (executed in phpMyAdmin) returns the results I want, but when I use PDO, it produces no results. I notice if I don't bind the values the query works, so would like to see what I am missing...

Below is the MySQL query:

```
SELECT AVG( demand_value ) 
FROM Demand
WHERE DATE = STR_TO_DATE(  '06 Nov 2013',  '%d %M %Y' ) 
AND TIME
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(  '07:00:00',  '%k:%i:%s' ) 
AND STR_TO_DATE(  '10:00:00',  '%k:%i:%s' );
```

Below is the PHP code (using PDO) trying to get the same results:

```
//Assume $date = '06 Nov 2013', $time_from = '07:00:00', $time_to = '10:00:00'
//Those values are parsed in from a custom function
$ave_btwn_times_stmt = 
$connection->get_conn()->prepare("SELECT AVG( demand_value ) 
FROM Demand
WHERE date = STR_TO_DATE(:date, '%d %M %Y')
AND time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:time_from, '%k:%i:%s') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(:time_to, '%k:%i:%s')");

$ave_btwn_times_stmt->bindValue(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ave_btwn_times_stmt->bindValue(':time_from', $time_from, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ave_btwn_times_stmt->bindValue(':time_to', $time_to, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ave_btwn_times_stmt->execute();
$ave_date_times = $ave_btwn_times_stmt->fetchAll();

echo "Average on " . $date . ", between " . $time_from . " and " . $time_to . ": " . $ave_date_times[0][0] . ".";
```

If I implement the code below, I get the results I am after:

```
$ave_btwn_times_stmt = 
$connection->get_conn()->prepare("SELECT AVG( demand_value )
FROM Demand 
WHERE date = STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d %M %Y')
AND time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from_time', '%k:%i:%s') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('$to_time', '%k:%i:%s')");                                             

$ave_btwn_times_stmt->execute();
$ave_date_times = $ave_btwn_times_stmt->fetchAll();

echo "Average on " . $date . ", between " . $time_from . " and " . $time_to . ": " . $ave_date_times[0][0] . ".";
```

If anyone can help me out on this one I would be very grateful.

Comment: Try using `errorInfo()` after your query

Comment: rather setup ypur pdo to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have done that in my custom 'Connection' class - $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);. I retrieve the connection with a method called get_conn();

Comment: This looks like impossible issue. 

And for all the hundreds of questions that looked impossible, most likely it's just a typo-like error. Even the form you are asking it, is suggestive. Your question doesn't looks like an solid investigation but rather like random pokes here and there. Do you have these code blocks indeed written in the same file and run at once?

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL query threw this error

> I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'TIME' in 'where clause'

I have refactored your query removing `BETWEEEN` and replacing it with  2 comparison tests.

```
SELECT AVG( demand_value ) FROM Demand 
       WHERE DATE = STR_TO_DATE( '06 Nov 2013',  '%d %M %Y' ) 
       AND  `time_from` >= STR_TO_DATE( `time_from`,'%k:%i:%s' ) 
       AND  `time_to` >= STR_TO_DATE(`time_to`,'%k:%i:%s' )
```

Using unnamed placeholders the following code provides required output.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    $ave_btwn_times_stmt= $dbh->prepare("SELECT AVG( demand_value )
    FROM Demand WHERE DATE = STR_TO_DATE( ?,  '%d %M %Y' )  
    AND  `time_from` >= STR_TO_DATE( ?,'%k:%i:%s' ) 
    AND  `time_to` >= STR_TO_DATE(?,'%k:%i:%s' )");                                             
    // Assign parameters
    $ave_btwn_times_stmt->bindParam(1,$date);
    $ave_btwn_times_stmt->bindParam(2,$time_from);
    $ave_btwn_times_stmt->bindParam(3,$time_to);
    $ave_btwn_times_stmt->execute();
    $ave_date_times = $ave_btwn_times_stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "Average on " . $date . ", between " . $time_from . " and " . $time_to . " = " . $ave_date_times[0][0] . ".";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

After testing you should remove the error echo, or Try/Catch block and relying on  [**PHP error handling**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) instead

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll definitely try this out in the morning. I'll need to ask the technician to give me access outside of the web root so I can append error messages to the log file and access them.